# Not able to install emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am new to Mobile automation. I am trying to create an AVD in Android Studio. I am getting the below error.

*Packages to install:

- Android Emulator (emulator)
  Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.7.5)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7491168.zip
  An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: C:\Program Files\Android\sdk.downloadIntermediates.
  "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.7.5)" failed.
  Failed packages:
- Android Emulator (emulator)*

The Steps I followed to create AVD is, Tools -> AVD Manager -> Create Virtual device ->Selected P4XL phone, Clicked on Q Download, then installation not successful. not sure what exactly i missed in configuration. can someone help me on this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely a permission problem as the Android SDK is installed in Program Files directory (where regular users don't have write permissions).

Answer (score 2):

You can manually download the System Image from here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7491168.zip.

And then go to Android Sdk Path,

> you can check out where you have put your Sdk by navigating to
> File/Project Structure/ Sdk Location.

Like for me it's D:\Android_SDK

And in here open the system-images folder.
Here you will see folders with different Android versions, if there isn't any create one according to the Android Version of your system_image like,

> android-30

And then create **google_apis** folder. Here extract the zip file you have downloaded. Then Open your Android Studio, you will then be able to select the system_image and create the AVD without downloading from Android Studio.

Comment: I am still not seeing emulator in android studio. I installed emulator separately placed in this location as mentioned Android\SDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis\emulator  .. I dont see installed emulator list in my android studio.. do i need to setup .. any path setup?

Comment: This is not the emulator you have installed, this is just a System Image. You have to create the emulator. To create a new Emulator just do all the steps as previous but this time you can choose the System Image directly without downloading again.

Comment: got it..  but my issue was with SDK installation.. So I tried uninstall SDK tools clean all.. installed back from Android studio.. this time it worked.. thanks for your help